# I am creating a chat application using react js. when i run the code the interface i made runs . but there is an error in a console

Tags: reactjs, list

that error is this "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Contact`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information." This error comes in five times with five different component names in my code **contact,massage,chat input,sidebar and message options** ("Check the render method of `Contact`") I will give you the code of my components and the errors related to them.`

**sidebar component code :-**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Gear } from "phosphor-react";
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import { Avatar, Box, Divider, IconButton, Stack, Menu, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useSettings from "../../hooks/useSettings";
import { Nav_Buttons, Profile_Menu } from "../../data";
import AntSwitch from '../../components/AntSwitch';
import Logo from "../../assets/Images/hearslLogo.png";



const SideBar = () => {
  const [selected, setselected] = useState(0);
  const { onToggleMode } = useSettings();
  const theme = useTheme();

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
  return (
    <Box p={2} sx={{
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      boxShadow: "0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)",
      height: "100vh",
      width: 100,
      alignItems: "center"
    }}
    >
      <Stack
        direction="column"
        alignItems={"center"}
        justifyContent="space-between"
        sx={{ height: "100%" }}
        spacing={3}
      >
        <Stack alignItems="center" spacing={4}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
              height: 64,
              width: 64,
              borderRadius: 1.5
            }}
          >
            <img src={Logo} alt={"chat app Logo"} />
          </Box>
          <Stack
            sx={{ width: "max-content" }}
            direction="column"
            spacing={3}
            alignItems="center"
          >
            {Nav_Buttons.map((el) => (
              <Box
                p={1}
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: el.index === selected ? theme.palette.primary.main : '',
                  borderRadius: 1.5,
                  alignItems: "center"
                }}
                key={el.index}
              >
                <IconButton
                  onClick={() => {
                    setselected(el.index);
                  }}
                  sx={{
                    width: "max-content",
                    color: el.index === selected ? "#fff" : theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#000" : theme.palette.text.primary
                  }}
                >
                  {el.icon}
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            ))}
            <Divider sx={{ width: "48px", alignItems: "center" }} />
            {selected === 3 ? (
              <Box
                p={1}
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                  borderRadius: 1.5,
                  display: 'flex',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <IconButton sx={{ width: "max-content", color: "#fff" }}>
                  <Gear />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            ) : (
              <IconButton onClick={() => {
                setselected(3);
              }}
                sx={{ width: "max-content", color: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#000" : theme.palette.text.primary }}
              >
                <Gear />
              </IconButton>
            )}
          </Stack>
        </Stack>

        <Stack spacing={4}>
          {/* Switch */}
          <AntSwitch onChange={() => {
            onToggleMode();
          }} defaultChecked />
          <Avatar id="basic-button" aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
            onClick={handleClick} src={faker.image.avatar()} />
          <Menu
            id="basic-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
              'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
            }}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "right"
            }}
            transformOrigin={{
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left"
            }}
          >
            <Stack spacing={1} px={1}>
              {Profile_Menu.map((el) => (
                <MenuItem key={el.id} onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Stack sx={{ width: 100 }} direction="row" alignItems={"center"} justifyContent="space-between">
                    <span>{el.title}</span>
                    {el.icon}
                  </Stack>{""}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Stack>
          </Menu>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default SideBar
```

I tried to solve this error by using chatgpt but after i added the changes said by chat gpt still these errors occurred. I got some of this error before but by using chatgpt i solved them and i also tried to solve them using geeksforgeeks tutorial to solve these errors. but i couldn't understand  that tutorial

Comment: you have common values for the key attribute. Try to choose something more elaborate like: `key={'box_item_' + el.index}`

Answer (score -1):

The warning message you're seeing, "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop," is a common React warning when rendering lists of components. To address this, you should use the index from the map function as the key prop for each item in your list.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
{yourArray.map((el, index) => (
  <YourComponent key={index} someProp={el.someValue} />
))}
```

[Official React documentation on keys](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
In the code above, we use index as the key prop, ensuring each element in the list has a unique identifier. However, it's essential to note that using the index as the key should be done with caution, especially when the list items can be reordered or modified. If possible, try to use a more stable and unique identifier as the key, such as an id from your data if available.

By applying this change, you can resolve the warning and ensure that React can efficiently update and manage your list of components.

For more information on this topic, you can refer to the official React documentation on keys.